# How to resolve Untracked changes in vscode ,i don't know git commands

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Here is the image ,styles.css is untracked so i'm not able to import it in the same directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBFps.png)

Comment: why not, `untracked` is just a label given by VSC/git to the file, the file is on disk so you can use it, you don't import CSS files you link CSS files

Comment: ho do i do that: import "./styles.css" doesn't work,,vscode says module can't be found ,this is a react app

Comment: how do you use CSS files in HTML files

Comment: using <link> but this is not normal HTML, this is JSX.